# Is there a Java/Kotlin function to find the placement of the currency symbol based on locale?

Tags: java, localization, apache-poi

I have a locale and a currency and I would like to know if I should place the currency symbol before or after the number?

I need to build the relevent Excel format string (for Apache POI) and I have everything I need to do so except for the placement of the currency symbol.

For example:

```
Locale: fr-FR
Currency: EUR
User expects to see: 10.99 €
Excel/POI format should be: #,##0.00 [$€-fr-FR]
```

```
Locale: nl-NL
Currency: EUR
User expects to see: €10.99
Excel/POI format should be: [$€-nl-NL] #,##0.00
```

The Locale class provides the language tag.
The Currency class provides the symbol and expected number of decimal places.

As far as I can find there's no way to find the expected placement other than formatting the string and then searching for the currency (as described here: [Location of currency symbol for a particular currency in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809078/location-of-currency-symbol-for-a-particular-currency-in-java)).

Comment: Not an answer, because I think your final paragraph is the best approach (I don't think there is an API for the currency format strings). But for reference, you can see currency format strings in the [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/) - for example [here](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/f443882bd0fc9267ad7b2b534da6428929bd7b0f/common/main/fr.xml#L7754) for French, and [here](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/f443882bd0fc9267ad7b2b534da6428929bd7b0f/common/main/nl.xml#L13591) for Dutch. I would absolutely not try to use these directly, myself.

Comment: Just for reference, Java does have [`DecimalFormat.toLocalizedPattern()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#toLocalizedPattern()), but this does not include information about the currency symbol, or its position - only the decimal number itself, even if you [set the currency explicitly](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setCurrency(java.util.Currency)).